# Check if current user belongs in group in workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I'm using SPD 2013, and want to know if there's a way to check if the current user is included in a group.  I'm trying to use it for a conditional to either run an approval process or not.

The closest I can get right now is: `If Workflow Context:Current User contains Approvers`

If I could switch the `Approvers` and `Current User` I would have exactly what I want, but to my knowledge you can't do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

With SharePoint 2013 workflows you can always use REST services to make the appropriate calls to SharePoint with the information you are looking for, so that anything outside the list of SharePoint workflow actions can be executed. You can make an HTTP Request action point to a web REST API.

Using the HTTP request:

```
http://sharepoint/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web
        /getbyname('Approvers')/Users?$filter=Id eq " + CurrentItem.CreatedBy.ID + "
        ?@target='http://sharepoint'
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Sadly I haven't worked much with REST services.  How would I go about using this in conjunction with my already working workflow in SPD?  I would just be wanting to add this as a conditional at the beginning.

Comment: Take a look at this link for a good overview of REST with SPD 2013 workflows from one of my colleagues: http://www.sparkhound.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=90 and here is another good article: http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2013/09/03/more-on-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-with-fiddler-and-spd/

Comment: I won't be able to use this with my existing workflow as it's a 2010 workflow.  I copied and modified the OOB Publishing Approval workflow.  I can try and work something out in a 2013 workflow then I would be able to go about it this way, but if I don't have to recreate the workflow that would be ideal.  The information you provided me will help out in many other areas though so thank you for that!

Comment: You won't be able to copy a 2010 workflow into 2013 unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah I meant trying to go through the trouble of rebuilding it in a 2013 workflow.  I'm not sure if it would work/how long it would take anyways.